Selling Chametz Without a Liquor License
Does the lack of a Liquor License render Mechirat Chametz halachically invalid, or draw it into question?
(Please note that this question is not about Prohibition, the repealed law which banned alcohol in the United States from 1920 -1933.)

Perhaps you'd like to ask first whether illegal sales are still sales after the fact.

A simple google search will show that an illegal sale will generally not be enforced. Furthermore, even if the sale would be legally binding, the buyer would be hesitant to openly admit involvement in illegal conduct by pursuing enforcement of the contract in court. This may draw semichat daas into question

that sounds like relevant information to include in the question above to help answerers properly address your question.

similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37004/759

What about if you live in an apartment and it has a "no sublets clause", yet you also rent out the space as part of the sale. Or you're a commuter from Teaneck and stop for mechirah in Manhattan -- now conducting interstate commerce. On the latter two, Rabbi Willig shlita feels that the sale is not "material" enough to warrant the state's concern, and therefore still a proper mechirah. Of course of the non-Jew instead wanted to pay up for all the chametz, then I imagine the rabbi should call a lawyer on how to handle the liquor transfer.

@Shalom Great point about "Rabbi Willig shlita feels that the sale is not "material" enough". What is wrong with selling food over state lines? Subleting is a different issue, separate from the sale of the actual chametz.  Mishnah Berurah writes that (if the landlord is a Jew), his permission should preferably be sought to sublease to the non-Jew. Alternatively, it should be rented to the non-Jew for storage purposes (not as a dwelling).

@Kirk The considerations for Prohibition are different from those of this question. For example, the top (only) answer on that question points out the selective enforcement of Prohibition. Furthermore, Prohibition has been repealed! (In my reading, that question also does not ask about the validity of the sale.)

I vote to reopen because this question is more nuanced. I was so impressed by it I was going to put up a bounty on it!

I'm no lawyer but I don't think you need a liquor license for  a commercial bulk inventory sale  that included some liquor inventory. The main issue is selling liquor for personal consumption

@Schmerel https://atcc.maryland.gov/Documents/Form/Alcohol-Forms/02-Permits/20-3A_PERMIT-application-for-a-private-bulk-sale-permit.pdf https://nj.gov/oag/abc/downloads/liquor_license_transfer_guide.pdf
